# New DJIKeyManager in DJI SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

In SDK 4.0, DJIKeyManager was introduced and I'd like to know when and how I should use it.

For example, the function

```
let batteryLevelKey = DJIBatteryKey(param: DJIBatteryParamChargeRemainingInPercent)

keyManager.startListeningForChanges(on: batteryLevelKey!, withListener: self, andUpdate: ....
```

provided by DJIKeyManager seems behaving the same as

```
battery(_ battery: DJIBattery, didUpdate batteryState: DJIBatteryState)
```

Answer (score 2):

You use like that

```
final BatteryKey batterLevelKey = BatteryKey.create(BatteryKey.CHARGE_REMAINING_IN_PERCENT);
    DJISDKManager.getInstance().getKeyManager().addListener(batterLevelKey, new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(@Nullable Object o, @Nullable Object o1) {
            int remainingChargeInPercentage = (int) o1;
            Log.d("remainingChargeInPercentage", remainingChargeInPercentage + "");
        }
    });
```